# find duplicates in html table using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a html table whose rows are added by click add button. The row will contain 4 drop downs 
Product Type  , Product Description,Source,destination1,destination 1

How Can I restrict the combination of these are not duplicated in any of the rows.

Comment: @Py,currently I don't have any code. I was looking at the :contains method of jquery. But Not able to implement it

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html)??

Comment: I was talking about the HTML, you should have some no?

Comment: @Py, Please find the html here http://sharetext.org/BF84

Comment: @S.M.09 No. Not in table. In html table

Comment: @user941974 : that is actually a HTML table(try looking at the code), Just CSS makes it look like that....and please can you explain me the difference between a table and HTML table?

Comment: @S.M.09, As you have the link using database table, I replied table. As for me here table is database table

Comment: @user941974: You have mistaken that is a simple HTML table....which may or may not be created from the data from the data base...look at a simpler example on the site....that would give you a better idea...it uses simple HTML table and transforms it into the one you see....

Comment: To be sure, you want that there is only one "sand", one "White Concrete", or are you looking for the uniqueness of the line (eg there could be a line "sand-white concrete" and a line "sand-scrap sand")?

Comment: @Py, yes there could be a line "sand-white concrete" and a line "sand-scrap sand".

Comment: @user941974: This is not a "make/fix this for me please" site. It's a "questions about programming languages" site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is just a check; it does not change dynamically the content to adapt it to the user change.

Using the html you provided, the function is the following:

```
function check(){
   var currentState=[],
       isGood=true,
       text;
   $("#dataFieldTable tr").each(function(index,element){
      if(index !==0){
          text=$(":selected",element).text();
          if(currentState.indexOf(text)!=-1){
              isGood=false;
              return false;
          }
          currentState.push(text);
      }
   });
   alert(isGood);
   return isGood;   
}
```

What it does is the following:

- Select all the `<tr>` tags in the table
- iterate over the tr we want to check (in my example, I took them all but the one with the title, but it's something easy to change , it's just the `if(index !==0)`)
- grab all the selected elements in the line
- concatenate their text value
- check whether it's different from the previous one
- if it's different, check the next one...
- if it's not, it's over.
- return true or false (and alert it) depending on the outcome.

And that's it.

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/uQGGW/1/

If you click check line, it will alert true if all the lines are different and false elsewhere.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks.Works Well. I will modify it to my need. To Highlight the duplicate rows.

Comment: I am trying to apply background color to each element. But the background is not getting applied.  [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/Bzbkn/1/)

Comment: I updated it a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/Bzbkn/5/ . You cannot apply background-color to select if I'm not mistaken. So i applied it to the line. I also removed the return false in order to iterate over all the loop.